# Overflow:hidden doesn't work on Xoom Browser

Tags: android, css, xoom

I have an image within a div container, that div container 
has the style "overflow:hidden" which works on all major browsers 
but for some reason doesn't work on Xoom, any ideas? 
What browser is that anyway?

Comment: It isn't working only with Xoom, or with any other Android-based device?

Comment: unfortunately I don't have more android devices, and the emulator is so slow i'm not planning on that adventure

Comment: Are you setting a meta-information for android mobile browser `<meta name="viewport" .... />` as described here: http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/targeting.html

Comment: should I do it only for Android devices (wrap it with an IF) or is it ok to use it for desktops as well?

Comment: Desktops will quietly ignore this stuff

Answer (score 0):

I've got a similar quandary in that overflow:auto stuff appears properly when the dom element is within the viewport, but once the element has moved above or below the viewport, it's content breaks free and becomes visible.

To answer your "what browser is that anyway", the User Agent I got during my tests was:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 3.1; en-us; Xoom Build/HMJ37) AppleWebKit/534.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Safari/534.13
```

The interface certainly *looks* like Chrome, but I guess it's a custom browser(?)
Paste that into http://useragentstring.com to get a pretty good analysis of the agent string.